# Issues when installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition on Windows 7 64bit platform.

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Now I want to install VS 2015 Enterprise but at the end of the installation some error messages appear saying:

Cannot find one or more components. Please re-install the application.

I have googled and tried some workarounds posted here like executing:

devenv

or

devenv /resetuserdata

but without success.

Despite these error messages I can accept them and complete the VS 2015 Enterprise installation. However, once installed, If I try to execute Visual Studio 2015 the same error appears and then I accept the message and it exits.

Any idea what is happening?

Error messages in the log:

```
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:40:09]i000: Setting string variable 'SecondaryInstallerDynamicItems' to value 'MicroUpdate2.3;AndroidNDK_64_V1;AntV1;XamarinVSV2;E_MDDCPlusPlus_ClangC2_V4;E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V6;E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V6;AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RTMV1_5.2.60322.1;GitHubVSV1;Gitx86V5;Gitx64V5;Xamarin_Preparation_Tool;PowerShellToolsV1;ClickOnceV1;PythonToolsForVisualStudioV5;Win10_VSTools_14.0.25219;MDDJSV10;AndroidSDK_API22V1;AndroidSDK_API23V1;AndroidSDK_API1921V1;JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25205;JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25205;Node.jsV1;JavaJDKV1;VS_SDKV4;AndroidNDKV1;VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV4;AndroidSDKV1;Win10SDK_Hidden_10.0.10240;Win10SDK_10.0.10586.212;VSU_14.0.25123;WebSocket4NetV1'
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:40:09]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space before install:  SystemDrive C:\ 75202260992 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 75202260992 bytes
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:42:17]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to launch elevated child process: C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Temp\{675a5109-38d6-406c-9e75-d0e922f87a58}\.be\vs_enterprise.exe
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:42:17]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError:The failed package () is not in the planned list.
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:42:17]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to elevate.
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:42:17]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to actually elevate.
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:42:17]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to elevate.
[0940:0E28][2016-05-14T22:42:17]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 3178496  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 3178496


[1498:0B38][2016-05-14T23:14:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7932CD6F-86D3-3EE4-8A02-B954404D1FFC}v14.95.25118\packages\TeamExplorer\Core\cab1.cab
[1498:0B38][2016-05-14T23:14:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to cache payload: cabCC98A656FE3BC5133D9AEC0E54E3D662
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]i000: MUX:  Verify Failed.  Retry acquiring, Retry Count: 1 of 3
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147024894 (0x80070002), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Verify, Package Id=vs_teamExplorerCore
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]e314: Failed to cache payload: cabCC98A656FE3BC5133D9AEC0E54E3D662 from working path: C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Temp\{675a5109-38d6-406c-9e75-d0e922f87a58}\cabCC98A656FE3BC5133D9AEC0E54E3D662, error: 0x80070002.
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]e349: Application requested retry of payload: cabCC98A656FE3BC5133D9AEC0E54E3D662, encountered error: 0x80070002. Retrying...
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]i304: Verified existing payload: cabCC98A656FE3BC5133D9AEC0E54E3D662 at path: V:\packages\TeamExplorer\Core\cab1.cab.
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]i338: Acquiring package: vs_teamExplorerCore, payload: cabCC98A656FE3BC5133D9AEC0E54E3D662, copy from: V:\packages\TeamExplorer\Core\cab1.cab
[0940:0E0C][2016-05-14T23:14:47]i000: MUX:  Reset Result

[0940:0E28][2016-05-15T01:37:27]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin for secondary installer
[0940:0E28][2016-05-15T01:37:28]i000: MUX:  Checking to see if the secondary installer pipe should be created
[0940:0E28][2016-05-15T01:37:28]i000: MUX:  Creating secondary installer pipe: {0fbc9528-ae1d-42d3-93da-9826e95f871e}
[0940:37C4][2016-05-15T01:37:30]i000: MUX:  Begin connecting secondary installer pipe
[0940:0E28][2016-05-15T01:37:30]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: VSSecondaryInstaller_box
[1498:1584][2016-05-15T01:37:34]i301: Applying execute package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E965494A4E5DF9A220D725F9909F655E078940F9\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E965494A4E5DF9A220D725F9909F655E078940F9\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe" /q /BurnBundleProviderKey {675a5109-38d6-406c-9e75-d0e922f87a58} /lcid 1033 /BaseDirectory "V:\\" /localfeed "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Temp\-687758302.xml" /FeedUriToRegister "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=646969&clcid=0x409" /FeedRegistryKey "Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\vs\enterprise" /primarylog "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_enterprise_20160514223321.log" /skuSpecificHKLMHive Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 /launchaction Install  /installitems JavaJDKV1;AndroidSDKV1;AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RTMV1_5.2.60322.1;JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25205;JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25205;MicroUpdate2.3;Win10SDK_10.0.10586.212;AndroidSDK_API1921V1;AntV1;AndroidNDK_64_V1;WebSocket4NetV1;Win10_VSTools_14.0.25219;AndroidSDK_API23V1;AndroidSDK_API22V1;Node.jsV1;Gitx64V5;Xamarin_Preparation_Tool;AndroidNDKV1;VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV4;VS_SDKV4;GitHubVSV1;E_MDDCPlusPlus_ClangC2_V4;E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V6;E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V6;MDDJSV10;XamarinVSV2;Win10SDK_Hidden_10.0.10240;PowerShellToolsV1;ClickOnceV1;PythonToolsForVisualStudioV5 /potentialcachecleanup ++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RTMV1_5.2.60322.1++AppInsightsToolsRTMCheck_HiddenV1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV2_4.0.51117.1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV3_4.0.51203.1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV4_4.1.60107.3++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV5_4.2.60128.3++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV6_4.3.60222.2++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2CTPV1_5.0.60115.1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RCV1_5.1.60222.1;++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25205++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV2++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV2++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV3++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV3++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV4++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV4++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25123A++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25123A;++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25205++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV2++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV2++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV3++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV3++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV4++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV4++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25123A++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25123A;++MicroUpdate2.3++MicroUpdate2++MicroUpdate2.1++MicroUpdate2.2;++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25219++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25208++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25123A++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25115++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25029++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25008++Win10_VSTools_14.0.24720++Win10_VSTools_14.0.24627++Win10_VSTools_14.0.23309++Win10_VSTools_14.0.23121++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25208++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25123A++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25115++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25029++Win10_VSTools_14.0.25008++Win10_VSTools_14.0.24720++Win10_VSTools_14.0.24627++Win10_VSTools_14.0.23309;++Gitx64V5++GitV1++GitV2++Gitx64V3++Gitx64V4;++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV4++VS_SDKV3++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV3++VS_SDKV2++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV2++VS_SDKV1++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV1;++VS_SDKV4++VS_SDKV3++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV3++VS_SDKV2++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV2++VS_SDKV1++VS_Extensibility_TemplatesV1;++E_MDDCPlusPlus_ClangC2_V4++E_MDDCPlusPlus_ClangC2_V1++E_MDDCPlusPlus_ClangC2_V2++E_MDDCPlusPlus_ClangC2_V3;++E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V6++MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V1++E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V2++E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V3++E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V4++E_MDDCPlusPlus_iOS_V5;++E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V6++E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V5++E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V4++E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V3++E_MDDCPlusPlus_Android_V2++MDDCPlusPlus_AndroidV1;++MDDJSV10++MDDJSV1++MDDJSV2++MDDJSV3++MDDJSV4++MDDJSV5++MDDJSV6++MDDJSV7++MDDJSV8++MDDJSV9++MDDJSV9A++MDDJSV91;++XamarinVSV2++XamarinVSV1;++PythonToolsForVisualStudioV5++PythonToolsForVisualStudioV1++PythonToolsForVisualStudioV2++PythonToolsForVisualStudioV3++PythonToolsForVisualStudioV4 /Pipe {0fbc9528-ae1d-42d3-93da-9826e95f871e} {1f77ca43-32b6-4384-9d88-57b67984d9ba} -burn.ancestors={675a5109-38d6-406c-9e75-d0e922f87a58}'
[0940:37C4][2016-05-15T01:38:03]i000: MUX:  Finished connecting secondary installer pipe
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T01:42:15]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Developer Analytics Tools v5.2.0, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T01:42:34]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=JavaScript Language Service para Visual Studio, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T01:48:08]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=JavaScript Project System para Visual Studio, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T01:54:09]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Instalación del SDK de Android (niveles de API 19 y 21), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T02:03:16]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Apache Ant (1.9.3), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T02:04:19]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Android Native Development Kit (R10E, 64 bits), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T10:34:08]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=WebSocket4Net, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T10:34:18]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Herramientas para aplicaciones universales de Windows (1.3.2) y SDK de Windows 10 (10.0.10586), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T12:10:37]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Instalación de Android SDK (Nivel API 23), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T12:14:26]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Instalación de Android SDK (Nivel API 22), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T12:15:02]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Kit de desarrollo nativo de Android (R10E, 32 bits), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T12:37:07]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Plantillas de elementos de extensibilidad para Visual Studio, actualización 2, con referencias de ensamblado en paquetes NuGet, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T12:46:39]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Kit de desarrollo de software de Visual Studio 2015, actualización 2, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T13:05:11]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Extensión de GitHub para Visual Studio, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T13:17:34]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Clang con Microsoft CodeGen (marzo de 2016), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T13:33:35]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Desarrollo de iOS de Visual C++ (Update 2), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T13:40:55]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Desarrollo de Android de Visual C++ (Update 2), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T13:46:37]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=HTML/JavaScript (Apache Cordova) Update 9, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T14:07:56]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=SDK de Windows 10 (10.0.10240), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T14:37:30]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Herramientas de PowerShell para Visual Studio, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T14:52:10]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Herramientas de publicación ClickOnce, Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T14:52:11]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Herramientas de Python para Visual Studio (marzo de 2016), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T14:56:25]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:07:08]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:07:37]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=KB3151378
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:31:39]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=KB3151378LP
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:31:44]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=Visual C++ IDE Debugger Package
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:31:56]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=Roslyn Language Services - x86
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:43:20]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:45:29]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=vs_update2notification
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:45:33]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation
[0940:0938][2016-05-15T15:46:15]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Actualización para Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3151378), Inner=
[1498:1584][2016-05-15T15:50:36]e000: Error 0x80048646: Process returned error: 0x80048646
[1498:1584][2016-05-15T15:50:37]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0940:0E28][2016-05-15T15:50:38]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

Comment: Your installation distributive might be corrupted. Try to re-download it (web installer or better, a complete ISO image)

Comment: I think it is not a problem of a corrupted distribution. I have another distribution and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed VS2015E on 4 VS2010 machines: 3 without issue 1 with problems of a similar nature.

There should be an install log in your %temp% directory (named dd_vs_enterprise_[datestamp]_netfxfullweb.log.html in my case)

For me the problems basically centered round the VS2015 not finding 64bit elements of the .net stack
Rebuilding the .net stack solved the immediate issue during install

Comment: What do you mean by rebuilding the .net stack? how to do it?

Comment: Reinstall the all the various part of the .net framework you have installed, then reregister these with the "aspnet_regiis -iru -enable" command - The command must run in each of .framework directories where the aspnet_regiis.exe executeable is located (eg C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework  +  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 + sub directory for each framework version)

Comment: I have done but it is not working yet. I will try to virtualize windows 7 from the scratch: install vs2010 then vs2015 and see what happens to discard a problem in OS.